# Can't redirect to diffrent method on the same controller under codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-2

Assume that I have a controller with two methods I want to redirect from method1 to method2 but it's not possible because of the following errors:

Chrome: `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.`

Firefox:`The page isn't redirecting properly`

How can I fix this?

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {
       function method1() {
           { ... Some Code ... }
            redirect('site/method2');
        }

        function method2() {
            { ... Rest of the code  ... }
        }
}
```

Comment: we are not going to assume anything. please post what you have tried?

Comment: Ok I tried to keep it simple. added the code, Thanks

Comment: Sounds like probably method2 is redirecting back to or calling method1. Can't tell without more code.

Comment: can you please put your htaccess code here

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.........

```
class example extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
            }

            public function method1(argument1)
            {
                   //your code
            }


            public function method2(argument2)
           {
               //your code

               $this->method1(arg);

                        or

              echo '<script language="javascript">top.location.href="'.ROOT_FOLDER.'/example/method1/'.$argument.'";</script>';
           }
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use `$this->method1` here. I'm looking for a way to this with redirect().

Comment: what you want exactly do you want to redirect to the view in calling method......

Answer (score 1):

THe problem is that you have to check your current `url` if it is the same url that you are planning to redirect then do not redirect here is an example,

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {
       function method1()
       {
           if(// all is GOOD)
           {
              $this->redirect('site','method2','args');
           }else{
              // Do something if the code fails
           }
        }

        function method2()
        {
           if(// all is GOOD)
           {
              $this->redirect('site','method1','args');
           }else{
              // Do something if the code fails
           }
        }

        function check_redirect($controller,$method,$args)
        {
           if($this->router->class !== $controller AND $this->router->method !== $method)
           {
              redirect($controller.'/'.$method.'/'.$args);
           }
        }
}
```

`The page isn't redirecting properly` happens when `method1` redirects to `method2` then when getting to `method2` it redirects back again to `method1` completing a none ending cycle of redirects.

this is just basic did not put any error handling. .